# Unescaping using saxutils, needs a byte-like object?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to get something out of a website and I'm getting this error

> data = data.replace("<", "<")
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
logincheck = logged_in.read();
soup = BeautifulSoup(logincheck, 'lxml');
cols = soup.find('textarea');
print(su.unescape(cols.renderContents()));
```

But when I check for `type(cols.renderContents())` it is byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly pointed out that `cols.renderContents()` is indeed a byte string.  The error in the `data = data.replace("<", "<")` line occurs because the library tries to call `.replace` on a byte string using `str`s (Unicode strings) as arguments.

To fix this error, you need to pass a Unicode string to `su.unescape`:

```
su.unescape(cols.renderContents().decode())
```